# How can I avoiding repetitive template specialization?

Tags: c++

I have some functions that work on a type defined by a C library.

The types are float_2, float_3, float_4, int32_2, int32_3, int32_4.

These types have something in common, a field named size. 
For float_2, size = 2. float_3, size = 3 etc.

Right now I have a template specialization for every single type.

```
static void add_number(rapidjson::Value &target, const char* name, float_2 src, Document::AllocatorType& alloc)
{   
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << src.x << " " << src.y;
    std::string s(ss.str());
    target.AddMember(StringRef(name), s, alloc);
}

static void add_number(rapidjson::Value &target, const char* name, float_3 src, Document::AllocatorType& alloc)
{   
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << src.x << " " << src.y << " " << src.z;
    std::string s(ss.str());
    target.AddMember(StringRef(name), s, alloc);
}
```

It would sure be nice to be able to do the following:

```
template <typename T>
static void add_number(rapidjson::Value &target, const char* name, T src, Document::AllocatorType& alloc)
{   
    std::ostringstream ss;
    switch(src.size){
      case 2: ss << src.x << " " << src.y;
      case 3: ss << src.x << " " << src.y << " " << src.z;
      case 4: ss << src.x << " " << src.y << " " << src.z << " " << src.w;
    }
    std::string s(ss.str());
    target.AddMember(StringRef(name), s, alloc);
}
```

But that doesn't work because these fields don't exist for all the types defined.  Is there some C++ magic template syntax that would allow me to avoid specializing every single case?

Comment: So each `float_` has a single parameter the same (`size`), but differ with `x`, `y` and `z`?

Comment: You cannot avoid specialization, here. Something, somewhere, has to be specialized. You might be able to offload specialization to a helper class, leaving add_number() to make that AddMember() call, with the helper class converting `src` into a `std::string`, but that's about it. A C++ compiler does not have artificial intelligence as part of the core language; as such one will have to write the code to do everything that needs to be done, one step at a time, be it in the form of specialized classes, or something else.

Comment: Correct.  The size field is common on all these types, oh except if T is a float.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I thought something might be possible with template metaprogramming which if I understand that allows you to execute code during compiliation, but I don't quite get how to use it or if it even applies in this instance.

Comment: You can overload `operator<<` for the different types: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, float_2 src) {
      return ss << src.x << " " << src.y;
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, float_3 src) {
      return ss << src.x << " " << src.y << " " << src.z;
    }` then use the template version and do `ss << src`

Comment: You can certainly use metaprogramming. But the end result will be approximately the same amount of code, at the very least, and which will be rather hard to follow and decipher. In the end, nothing useful would be accomplished. The current simple approach is rather straightforward, and gets the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this has to do with printing alone, size or any other specialization requirement. However, I think the least amount of specialization for the case presented is overloading the streaming operator for the different cases. That would look like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const float_2 &vec)
{
    return stream << vec.x << ", " << vec.y;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const float_3 &vec)
{
    return stream << vec.x << ", " << vec.y << ", " << vec.z;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const float_4 &vec)
{
    return stream << vec.x << ", " << vec.y << ", " << vec.z << ", " << vec.w;
}

template < typename T >
static void add_number(rapidjson::Value &target, const char* name, const T &src, Document::AllocatorType& alloc)
{   
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << src;
    std::string s(ss.str());
    target.AddMember(StringRef(name), s, alloc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use "template magic" to (remove function templates from the) overload (set). If there aren't more than about ten different types I'd rather go for `operator<<` overloads, however.

```
namespace detail
{

    template <class T, class = int> struct has_z : std::false_type { };
    template <class T> struct has_z <T, decltype((void)T::z, 0)> : std::true_type { };

    template <typename T>
    static auto foo_impl(T src)
        -> std::enable_if_t<!has_z<T>::value>
    {
        std::cout << "1: " << src.x << " " << src.y << "\n";
    }

    template <typename T>
    static auto foo_impl(T src)
        -> std::enable_if_t<has_z<T>::value>
    {
        std::cout << "2: " << src.x << " " << src.y << " " << src.z << "\n";
    }

}

template<class T>
void foo(T src)
{
    detail::foo_impl(src);
}
```

Now you can use `foo` on every type that has an `x`, a `y` and optionally a `z` member:

```
struct A { double x{ 1 }, y{ 2 }; };
struct B { double x{ 3 }, y{ 4 }, z{ 5 }; };

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
1 2
3 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks for that!  I've gone for the stream overload version in the end.  I think it's slightly shorter.